# Кнопка и горячие клавиши браузера

Tags: javascript, html

Создал `<button>` и хочу, чтобы она активизировала встроенный в браузер `hotkey`,в моем случае нужна функция (`Ctrl+S`) для сохранения уже загруженной страницы.
Можно как нибудь написать в javascript функцию для активации (`Ctrl+S`) посредством нажатия на `<button>`.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, нашел два вопроса на большом SO:

- [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12187302/5275890)
- [Keydown Simulation in Chrome fires normally but not the correct key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10520017/5275890)

Проблем с имитацией нажатия одной кнопки нет, все прекрасно работает и для первого случая и для второго. Но вот в чем беда - комбинация клавиш - не работает как хотелось бы. Почитав документацию по [KeyboardEvent.initKeyEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/initKeyEvent)

> `ctrlKeyArg` - Is a Boolean that is `true` if the virtual key to be
>   generated is a combination of keys containing the Ctrl key.

что в моем понимании, если укажем `true`, то событие представляет собой комбинацию клавиш, содержащих клавишу `Ctrl` (вроде бы проблем с английским нет). Ставим `true` - и желаемой комбинации не происходит. Но вот если указать `ctrlKeyArg`, `altKeyArg`, `shiftKeyArg` и `metaKeyArg` в значение `true`, то произойдет желаемое событие совместно с `Ctrl`.

Теперь к коду, привожу код, который имитирует нажатие `Ctrl+S`. Для наглядности добавил `addEventListener` на событие `keydown`, чтобы убедиться в том, что была нажата комбинация клавиш `Ctrl+S`:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  var ctrl = e.ctrlKey ? e.ctrlKey : ((key === 17) ? true : false);
  if (key == 83 && ctrl) { // ctrl+s
    console.log('ctrl+s');
  }
}, false);

Podium = {};
Podium.keydown = function(k) {
  var oEvent = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');

  Object.defineProperty(oEvent, 'keyCode', {
    get: function() { return this.keyCodeVal; }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(oEvent, 'which', {
    get: function() { return this.keyCodeVal; }
  });

  if (oEvent.initKeyboardEvent) {
    oEvent.initKeyboardEvent("keydown", true, true, window, true, true, true, true, k, k);
  } else {
    oEvent.initKeyEvent("keydown", true, true, window, true, true, true, true, k, 0);
  }

  oEvent.keyCodeVal = k;
  document.dispatchEvent(oEvent);
}

function func() {
  Podium.keydown(83);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="func();">btn</button>
```

И самое главное в завершении - диалоговое окно для сохранения страницы не всплывает, хотя имитируется нажатие `Ctrl+S`.

Comment: Спасибо.Я посмотрел код...он полностью работает,но окно действительно не всплывает...!Попробуем поискать что-то еще...Кажется все просто,но на практики что-то не так всегда!